# Significance of '60' for cointype?

Tags: history, keymanagement

When [constructing the path](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#path-levels) for a node in a wallet tree, [the default value for cointype is 60](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/84#issue-143651804) for ethereum.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3k6sji/ether_should_have_a_slip0044_coin_type_of_60/) and a [pull request about SLIP-0044](https://github.com/satoshilabs/docs/pull/51), it's because the symbol for Ether is Ξ, which is [60 in greek numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_%28letter%29).

Comment: There doesn't seem to have been much discussion on this. Crazy that a reddit post with 2 comments is all it took to make that decision.